# how to eval regular expression with embedded perl code

Tags: regex, perl, eval

So I tested out a regular expression that utilizes the experimental embedded code features.  My tests worked, so I expounded upon it to do a more sophisticated script, but ran into errors.  I traced the errors to a simple use of a variable in the regular expression not in the embedded code.  I tried doing the regex in the suggested eval, but discovered that that wouldn't work because I could not access special variables after the eval'ed regular expression.  I eventually re-wrote the code to not use the embedded code strategy, but am left curious as to why it wouldn't work.  I simplified the problem in a pair of perl one-liners below:

This works:

```
perl -e '$_ = "The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ABC god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb ehT";
    while (/(.{10,41})(?{$cap = $^N;$rev = r($cap);})(...)(??{$rev})/ig {
        print("$1\n")
    }
    sub r { return(join("",reverse(split("",$_[0])))) }'
```

So why doesn't this?:

```
perl -e '$_ = "The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ABC god yzal eht revo spmuj xof nworb ehT";
    $f=10;
    $e=41;
    while (/(.{$f,$e})(?{$cap = $^N;$rev = r($cap);})(...)(??{$rev})/ig) {
        print("$1\n")
    }
    sub r { return(join("",reverse(split("",$_[0])))) }'
```

The error I get is:

```
Eval-group not allowed at runtime, use re 'eval' in regex 
m/(.{10,41})(?{$cap = $^N;$rev = r($cap);})(...)(??{$rev})/ at -e line 1.
```

Is there a way to make it work with the `$f` and `$e` variables - a way that allows me to use the special variables

```
$`, $&, $', and @-
```

afterwards?  Do I need to use eval?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: One question that comes to mind is why do you have a subroutine that does exactly what [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) does in scalar context? `$rev = reverse($^N)` is all you need.

Comment: Yes. I do know that, but thanks for pointing it out. I originally had the code you suggested, but as I mentioned, I was testing for some more sophisticated code and I wanted to call a sub in the subsequent version that did something else.  So that's why I created the useless sub in my test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
use re 'eval';
```

It lets Perl know you are aware that the pattern being interpolated can evaluate arbitrary code and that you're ok with that. It's lexically-scoped, so it will only affect the regular expressions in the file or in the curlies where it is used.

Since you have a one-liner, you can do the same using the command line option

```
-Mre=eval
```

Comment: To my knowledge, `use re 'eval';` doesn't affect access to any variable, and your code works fine when I add that line, so you'll have to be clearer about what you mean by "a way that allows me to use the special variables `$\``, `$&`, `$'`, and `@-`".

Comment: I was wrapping my pattern match in an eval and the resultant values of those variables appeared to be junk.  I apparently did not understand that the error was telling me to add the line "use re 'eval'" to my code.  I'd thought it was suggesting that I wrap the regex in an eval.

Comment: Yes, other than "-Meval=re" should be "-Mre=eval".  Thanks!