# How to match same length digits in a string using regex

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I want to find a text (for example: stack) in a String that contains digits and chars (for example: s123t123a123c123k). The only rule is that between every character of the search key there should be the same amount of digits, so all of this should match:

```
search key: stack

Strings:
stack                  //0 digit between chars of stack
s7t3a9c0k              //1 digit between chars of stack
s27t33a49c50k          //2 digit between chars of stack
s127t312a229c330k      //3 digit between chars of stack and so on for 4,5,6 digits...
```

If I could match same length digits then I can write something like: s[]*t[]*a[]*c[]*k if the regex for same length digit is [].
How to match same length digits in a string using regex?

Comment: Just do it programmatically - match all digits, count the length of each group and you're done. Regular expressions are not for couting (unless you specify the length beforehand, e.g. `x{3}`).

Comment: With Perl, it is possible, using "postponed" regular subexpressions.

Comment: Hi, did my answer prove useful to you?

Comment: Not really, I needed a solution with no programming and only regex. But I don't think this is possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, the only regex solution is like the one in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do that with Perl, you may use

```
m/s(\d+)t(??{ "\\d{".length($^N)."}" })a(??{ "\\d{".length($^N)."}" })c(??{ "\\d{".length($^N)."}" })k/
```

Or, if you want to match digits with `[0-9]`:

```
m/s([0-9]+)t(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })a(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })c(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })k/
```

In the Perl code, you will most likely want to build the pattern dynamically. See the full Perl code demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use re 'eval'; # stackoverflow.com/a/16320570/3832970

my @input = split /\n/, <<"END";
s7t3a9c0k
s27t33a49c50k
s127t312a229c330k
s1t312a22c3300k
END

my $keyword = "stack";
my $pattern = substr($keyword, 0, 1) . '([0-9]+)' . join( '(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })', split("", substr($keyword, 1)) );
#my $pattern = substr($keyword, 0, 1) . '(\d+)' . join( '(??{ "\\\\d{".length($^N)."}" })', split("", substr($keyword, 1)) );
for my $input ( @input ) {
    if ($input =~ m/$pattern/) {
        print $input . ": PASS!\n";
    } else {
        print $input . ": FAIL!\n"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
s7t3a9c0k: PASS!
s27t33a49c50k: PASS!
s127t312a229c330k: PASS!
s1t312a22c3300k: FAIL!
```

The `$pattern` is built dynamically: `substr($keyword, 0, 1)` gets the first char, then `([0-9]+)` is added, then `join( '(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })', split("", substr($keyword, 1))` adds the following: it inserts `(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })` in between each char of the `$keyword` substring from the second char.  The `(??{ "[0-9]{".length($^N)."}" })` part acts as a `\d{X}` pattern where `X` is the length of the most recent captured substring (it was `([0-9]+)`).

The `use re 'eval';` is necessary to build the pattern dynamically. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16320570/3832970), *it will only affect the regular expressions in the file or in the curlies where it is used*.